# Ошибка при авторизации The presented password is invalid. symfony 3

Tags: symfony3

Всем привет, использую symfony 3.4 
Пытаюсь авторизоваться под уже созданным пользователем постоянно получаю
The presented password is invalid.
При этом уверен что логин пароль правильные. 
И так для любого пользователя, кто сталкивался? ну или хотя бы в какую сторону надо копать?

Comment: «Уже созданному пользователю» пароль шифровали? Тем же алгоритмом, с той же солью (если соль используется алгоритмом шифрования)?

Comment: да, ошибка хэш пароль исключена, не авторизовываются любые пользователи в логи пишет что пароль неверный